# Uninitialized constant error using Ruby in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Has anyone used RubyMine who could help me out?

I am new to RubyMine, and when I create my first project and add a few classes and wire them together for a simple meaningless application I am getting this error:
"uninitialized constant RubyApp (NameError)"

But when I take all the classes and put them in one file then run it, it runs fine.

What am I missing about using RubyMine here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Between taking several minutes to launch and over 20 seconds to open even the most trivial of files, I came to the conclusion that it really isn't a very useful product.

Comment: rubyMine 2011 is great!  The time to startup and launch, etc. is because of the the introspection is does.  This is a very old discussion and is basically a 'tortoise and hare' or 'sprint vs marathon' issue.  If you are editing one text file that relates to no others use the simplest editor available (notepad, vi, gedit, etc.).  However if you are building real applications where changes get tested and you like thousands of little tools that can help you write GOOD code and not just 'code' and you like having an invisible helper by your side than you will realize the strength of an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "RubyApp" one of your classes?
If so, it sounds like you're not requiring the other ruby files you're creating.

RubyMine pretty much doesn't get in your way at all, although it does like having gems 'attached' to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your case, since I've only run into this issue with gems. But, Rubymine requires you to link the gems your using and what not into your project settings for things to work. At least that is how I remember it when I tried it out.

Comment: hmmm... but how does this explain it working fine if I put all the classes in one file?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't put all the classes into one file. But you would configure the Rubymine project to know what to use and where to look for things. My basic understanding of how Rubymine works is that it creates an isolated env. within the app for your project. So if you need access to a gem you not only have to require "...", as usual, but you also have to add it to the list of gems available to the project.

Comment: I used Rubymine during their beta, so not sure if things have changed since. So I could be totally off.